# Regex match, how to return TRUE/FALSE

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am trying to work with a program that uses Regex matching with even a sheet at https://www.regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx to give examples of characters to use, and I have the ability to test at http://www.sweeting.org/mark/html/revalid.php#chars

What I have not been able to figure out yet is how to return a TRUE/FALSE like a normal if statement, if there is a match.

regular expression ^go
will match entered text of "go up hill"
But I am just looking for a TRUE return.

I am not sure of what the underlying language is being used.

Comment: Regex is used to match some text. To return true or false, you need to use the corresponding code, or regex function/method.

Comment: The 'truthiness' of a regex match depends on the environment. What language?